# Mix Warsaw and Madrid beamer theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

This is my first question. Be patience please.

In `beamer` class, I want the headline of Warsaw (you know, not only current `section` and `subsection` but also all sections and all subsections of the current section) and the footline of Madrid: author, university, short title, date and page number.

If you could also remove the toolbar in bottom right corner of the frame it would be perfect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you a MWE?

Comment: @Sebastiano: What is MWE?

Comment: **Minimum Working Example**:  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Madrid` uses the footline from the `infolines` outer theme. You can simply copy the definition to use it together with `Warsaw`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

% from infolines outer theme
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

% remove navigation
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\subsection{blub}
\begin{frame}
    I prefer cats! =(\^{}.\^{})=
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. And... What would be the code to add the "Warsow's headers" to Madrid theme?

Comment: @Dog_69 you can simply look this up http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeshadow.sty but copying the footline is usually easier.