# Load specific template from another theme

Tags: beamer

> Inspired by the discussion on https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/388

There are many questions on this site like "I use theme X but I'd like to have the footer/header/whatever from theme Y", just one example: [Mix Warsaw and Madrid beamer theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346686/mix-warsaw-and-madrid-beamer-theme)

To make this easier, how could one just load a specific template from a theme, for example just the footline?

---

Test cases

> Test 1: simple case

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[infolines theme]
```

> Test 2: test if it works with parent theme

```
\usetheme{Boadilla} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[infolines theme]
```

> Test 3: test if it works with options

```
\usetheme[height=3cm]{Rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[sidebar theme]
```

Comment: (definitely samcarter will know the answer) (wait... op is samcarter)

Comment: @Symbol1 Problem: I don't know a **good** answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Test 1

This seems to work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
    \useoutertheme{split}
\makeatletter
    \let\beamer@@@@sbto@old=\beamer@@@@sbto
    \def\text@footline{footline}
    \long\def\beamer@@@@sbto#1#2[#3]#4[#5]#6{
        \def\text@element{#1}
        \ifx\text@footline\text@element
            \beamer@@@@sbto@old{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5]{#6}
        \fi
    }
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \let\beamer@@@@sbto=\beamer@@@@sbto@old
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Test 2

If you want to gain the control over colors, do the same trick on `\beamer@clearbeamercolor` and `\beamer@setbeamercolor`.

(The same for `\setbeamerfont` and `\setbeamersize`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
    \useoutertheme{split}
\makeatletter
    \let\beamer@@@@sbto@old=\beamer@@@@sbto
    \def\text@footline{footline}
    \long\def\beamer@@@@sbto#1#2[#3]#4[#5]#6{
        \def\text@element{#1}
        \ifx\text@footline\text@element
            \beamer@@@@sbto@old{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5]{#6}
        \fi
    }
    \let\beamer@clearbeamercolor@old=\beamer@clearbeamercolor
    \let\beamer@setbeamercolor@old=\beamer@setbeamercolor
    \def\beamer@clearbeamercolor#1#2{}
    \def\beamer@setbeamercolor#1#2{}
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[infolines theme]
    \let\beamer@@@@sbto=\beamer@@@@sbto@old
    \let\beamer@clearbeamercolor=\beamer@clearbeamercolor@old
    \let\beamer@setbeamercolor=\beamer@setbeamercolor@old
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Test 3

In this test, it is essential that `\beamer@@@@sbto` is a long macro.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
    \useoutertheme{split}
\makeatletter
    \let\beamer@@@@sbto@old=\beamer@@@@sbto
    \def\text@headline{headline}
    \long\def\beamer@@@@sbto#1#2[#3]#4[#5]#6{
        \def\text@element{#1}
        \ifx\text@headline\text@element
            \beamer@@@@sbto@old{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5]{#6}
        \fi
    }
    \usetheme[height=3cm]{Rochester}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[sidebar theme]
    \let\beamer@@@@sbto=\beamer@@@@sbto@old
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{TEST}
    \begin{frame}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! On the first look this seems indeed to work very well! I will test it a bit and report back.

Comment: OK, I thought a bit about possible test cases and came up with 3 ones (see edit to my question) which should cover a broad spectrum of possible use cases. 1) you passed with flying colours :) 2) loading the parent theme also works, slight disadvantage is that things like colours will be overwritten by the theme. 3) for a theme with options I get an error `Paragraph ended before \beamer@@@@sbto was complete.`, but maybe I did not modify your solution correctly to now select a headline instead of a footline, as in the previous test.

Comment: Bonus point: with your approach one does not need to know the exact name of the template, e.g. all ones needs is `footline` and not that the footline in infolines is called `infolines theme` .

Comment: @samcarter It seems `\beamer@@@@sbto` is a long macro. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A clumsy workaround: Using the `catchfilebetweentags` package. However this needs some additional comments in the `.sty` files.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{split}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newcommand\fromtheme[2]{\ExecuteMetaData[beamertheme#1.sty]{#2}}
\newcommand\fromcolortheme[2]{\ExecuteMetaData[beamercolortheme#1.sty]{#2}}  
\newcommand\fromfonttheme[2]{\ExecuteMetaData[beamerfonttheme#1.sty]{#2}}  
\newcommand\fromoutertheme[2]{\ExecuteMetaData[beameroutertheme#1.sty]{#2}}
\newcommand\frominnertheme[2]{\ExecuteMetaData[beamerinnertheme#1.sty]{#2}}  

\fromoutertheme{infolines}{footline:infolines}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `.sty` files would need comments like:

```
%<*footline:infolines>
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
%</footline:infolines>

%<*headline:infolines>
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
%</headline:infolines>
```

**Problems of the above Ansatz:**

- comments of the form `%<*footline:infolines>` , `%</footline:infolines>` would have to be inserted in the code, custom made themes would probably not do this and user would be confused for which templates it would work and for which ones not.
- I know just loading a specific template will break as soon as the template tries to use something defined within the theme, but outside the template, for example things like `\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{...}` would have to be inside the `<*tag>`...`</tag>`
- of course it would be more convenient if one would not have to know in which sub-theme the template is defined, but could just insert the general theme and this command would recursivly search the loaded sub-themes for a given tag.
- I have not yet thought about how optional arguments of themes would fit into this...
- ....

---

**Results of the test cases:**

> Test 1: simple case

works

> Test 2: test if it works with parent theme

fail

> Test 3: test if it works with options

fail

Answer (score 1):

> The following code is from louisstuart96 in an answer I received at https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/388#issuecomment-296338235
>
> [in case he decides to add an answer himself, I will delete this CM]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{split}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@original@defbeamertemplate\beamer@defbeamertemplate
\def\beamer@defbeamertemplate{\beamer@sbtfalse\@ifstar{\beamer@sbtoo}{\beamer@sbtoo}}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[infolines theme] 
% This \set must be done manually, 
% since generally theme names have nothing to do with file names
\let\beamer@defbeamertemplate\beamer@original@defbeamertemplate
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

**Results of the test cases:**

> Test 1: simple case

works

> Test 2: test if it works with parent theme

works [with the slight disadvantage is that things like colours will be overwritten by the theme]

> Test 3: test if it works with options

works